# Detecting patterns in data with Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

i'm totally new to Tableau but that is what I could potentially use at the workplace, so asking this question to decide if its worth it.
I've a monthly values dataset and I'd like the tool (Tableau) to generate a report to point out anomalies - the ones i have in mind right now are:
1) same data value for x months in a row
2) data value is 0
3) 5 parameters been reported last 3 months and all of sudden only 4 are reported

Is this possible in Tableau?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do this. The below is a general example for doing anomaly detection (one standard deviation outside of mean) but you can modify the calc to fit your criteria. If you place your date field in the column position and your metric, lets say `Sales`, in the row position you can then create this calculated field to label the anomalies.

```
IF SUM([Sales]) <  (WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Sales])) – WINDOW_STDEV(SUM([Sales]))) THEN “Bad 
Anomaly”
ELSEIF SUM([Sales]) > (WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Sales])) + WINDOW_STDEV(SUM([Sales]))) THEN 
“Good Anomaly”

ELSE “Expected”
END
```

You can then place the new field on your color mark to highlight each of the results.

Comment: https://playfairdata.com/how-to-do-anomaly-detection-in-tableau/